# firebase iOS phone authentication testflight

Tags: ios, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication, testflight

I have uploaded my app to the App Store and added some internal testers in my itunes connect (including myself), we all receive the testflight invitation and we all can install the app. So far so so good. 
The app uses firebase phone authentication, and only myself is receiving the text message with the verification code. 
Why could this be happening?

I´ve tried typing another phone number from my phone and that phone number receives the SMS.

Does the internal tester need a developer account for this to work? That´s the only difference between both accounts.